# How does implementing an interface give us a strongly typed API?

Tags: c#

In C# in depth, Jon Skeet uses `IEquatable<>` to <strike>override</strike> overload the `Equals()` operation.

```
public sealed class Pair<T1, T2> : IEquatable<Pair<T1, T2>>
{
    public bool Equals(Pair<T1, T2> other)
    {
       //...
    }
}
```

He says we do this "to give a strongly typed API that'll avoid unnecessary execution-time checks".

Which execution time checks are avoided?  More importantly, how does implementing an interface achieve a strongly typed API?

I may have missed something in the book's context. I thought interfaces gave us code re-use via polymorphism.  I also understand that they are good for programming to an abstraction instead of a concrete type.  That's all I'm aware of.

Comment: It doesn't *override* Equals - it *overloads* Equals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default [`Equals` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx) takes an `object` as the parameter. Thus, when implementing this method, you have to make a runtime check in your code to ensure that this object is of type `Pair` (before you can compare those two):

```
public override bool Equals(Object obj) {
    // runtime type check here
    var otherPair = obj as Pair<T1, T2>;
    if (otherPair == null)
        return false;

    // comparison code here
    ...
}
```

The `Equals` method of [`IEquatable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx), however, takes a `Pair<T1,T2>` as a type parameter. Thus, you can avoid the check in your implementation, making it more efficient:

```
public bool Equals(Pair<T1, T2> other)    
{    
    // comparison code here
    ...
}
```

Classes such as `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, `List<T>`, and `LinkedList<T>`  are smart enough to use `IEquatable<T>.Equals` instead of `object.Equals` on their elements, if available (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx)).

Comment: In the book Jon regularly refers to improving API's through the use of generics.  I believe thats what he meant by the API part, strong typing vs object casting by implementing a *generic* interface.

Answer (score 3):

In this case he's providing a strongly typed version of `Object.Equals`, which will replace code that might look like the following:

```
public override bool Equals(object other)
{
    // The following type check is not needed with IEquatable<Pair<T1, T2>>
    Pair<T1, T2> pair = other as Pair<T1, T2>;
    if (pair != null)
    {
        // <-- IEquatable<Pair<T1, T2>> implementation
    }
    else
    {
        return base.Equals(other);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `IEquatable<T>` interface provides a strongly typed implementation of the `Equals` method, as opposed to the `Equals` method in `System.Object` that receives a `System.Object`.

Answer (score 0):

I think Jon saying "strongly typed" talks about generics.

I haven't found non-generic `IEquitable` interface but `IComparable<T>` vs. `IComparable` exist.

Comment: There's no need for a non-generic IEquatable interface given that `object` already has `Equals(object)`

Answer (score 0):

To be fair to Skeet (although sure he will be along soon) he does devote time to discussing what "strong typing" means in section 2.2.1.

In the context of your question (page 85 in my edition)), I think he means that the default Equals method (which takes an object as an argument) defers to the strongly-typed Equals method that implements the interface.